# 2 values in 1 column display under 2 seperate column headings

Tags: sql

We have values `599` and `616` in column `subs_box_service_num`

In our `Select` we have

```
subs_box_service_num AS D_FCS
subs_box_service_num AS D_PZR
```

The query is producing 2 columns with these different headers - good

How do we get the values 599 and 616 to display under the specific column(s)?

- we want values 599 to display under D_FCS
- we want values 616 to display under D_PZR

Comment: What database system are you using? Are the data related in any specific way? What is the expected input and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a pivoting query.  You don't specify what the rest of the query is returning.  Let me assume it is returning two rows with these values and there is another column clarifying the type.  The query would be:

```
select max(case when thetype = 'FCS' then subs_box_service_num end) as D_FCS,
       max(case when thetype = 'PZR' then subs_box_service_num end) as D_PZR
```

Of course, the specific details in your case depend on what else the query is doing and on which database you are using.  However, this approach of using conditional aggregation should work.

EDIT:

Your query is:

```
Select Distinct system_code, subs_acct_num, subs_box_service_num AS D_FCS,   
       subs_box_service_num AS D_PZR
From ABC_reporting.dbo.subscriber_boxes_addr_serv
Where subs_box_service_num IN('599','616')
```

What you seem to want is:

```
Select system_code, subs_acct_num,
       max(case when subs_box_service_num = 599 then subs_box_service_num end) AS D_FCS,   
       max(case when subs_box_service_num = 616 then subs_box_service_num end) AS D_PZR 
From ABC_reporting.dbo.subscriber_boxes_addr_serv
Where subs_box_service_num IN('599','616')
Group by system_code subs_acct_num;
```

This seems like a strange query.  Normally you would want some value associated with each type.

Comment: This i what we have so far

Comment: Select Distinct
system_code,
subs_acct_num,
subs_box_service_num AS D_FCS,
subs_box_service_num AS D_PZR

From ABC_reporting.dbo.subscriber_boxes_addr_serv 

Where subs_box_service_num IN('599','616')

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have done the trick, I still have some tweaking to do but this got me over this bump!